# How to configure Hue-2.5.0 and HIve-0.11.0

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

From past 2 days I have been working on setting up Hue but no luck.

The versions I tried with hive 0.11.0 :- 3.5, 3.0, 2.4, 2.1, 2.3, 2.5

After much googling i came to know 3.5 and 3.0 (documentation says 0.11) are compatible with hive 0.12 or 0.13 but as mine is 0.11 I faced issues like : Required client protocal , no database found, list index error.

Finally I was able to set up Hue 2.5.0 and it indeed connects with hiveserver2.

My Properties in hue.ini :

```
beeswax_server_host=localhost
server_interface=hiveserver2
beeswax_server_port=10000
hive_home_dir=/usr/lib/hive/hive-0.11.0
hive_conf_dir=/usr/lib/hive/hive-0.11.0/conf
```

All my tables are in hive which hiveserver2 does not show if I access it using "beeline"
but if I start hive thrift server then I can access all my tables and schemas in R-studio.

**I'm not getting why hiverserver2 cannot access hive tables, is it something different?**

Hue.ini file give only two options : beeswex and hiveserver2 for connectivity.

I have done a lot of online google but this point nothing is helping.

**please let me know if :**

**hiverserver2 can import hive data**

OR

**hiverserver can be used with hue 2.5.0**

OR

**if I'm missing anything**

If there is any more information required please let me know.

Comment: without CDH manger i need connect hiveserver 1 from Hive server2 ..

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hive is missing some patches from CDH that have not been accepted by the community. The Thrift protocol version is also different depending depending on the release.

The current workarounds are to cherry-pick the missing patches from CDH or to use Hive from CDH.

You can read more [here](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/hue-user/mKWDwZs0gB0) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a hive client installed on the Hue machine, with a configured hive-site.xml.

Then you can comment out all the [[beeswax]] section and Hue should run correctly.